# Zend setDestination() is not working when called after isValid()

Tags: zend-framework

I am a newbie in zend and I am currently trying to make file uploading work. 
Actually I can already upload files to the destination directory that I specified, but
when I call setDestination() after isValid(), it will upload the file to the tmp directory.

Is there some kind of rule that setDestination() should be called before isValid()?

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
// add some validators here

if ($upload->isValid()){
    //if extension is jpg
    $upload->setDestination("<some directory>/jpg");
    //else
    $upload->setDestination("<some directory>");

   $upload->receive();
}
```

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$info = $upload->getFileInfo();
move_uploaded_file($info['tmp_name'], $destination);
```

Comment: thank you for your advise. unfortunately, it didn't work too. :(